# What partition types should I use for my external HDD? Will the choice affect the performance?

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive, external-drive, easeus-partition-manager

**Background**

I have a 2TB external HDD with two partition = 1.6 TB for files+ 300GB for system image(made after ransomware attack).

The 300GB partition is NTFS format with partition type primary.
The 1.6TB partition is FAT32 with primary.

I want to change my FAT32 to NTFS so which partition type should I use.

Because to convert FAT32 to NTFS I created a new NTFS partition to transfer my FAT32 partition files to it and then format it to NTFS but the new partition I created was made logical type by default (I didn't knew about it then).

But now when I have been moving files I see some significant performance change, the files are taking more time to transfer.

**Question**

1. What's the difference between various partition types?
2. Which partition type should I use then?
3. Does the partition type affect performance too?

---

**PS**: I use my 1.6TB partition to store general files, edited videos and images, movies, and games.

I am using Ease Us for partition management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no performance difference. Whatever you're experiencing is not caused by partition types.

---

Now technical details.

Your disk is partitioned using the old MBR scheme which is kinda obsolete now (GPT is the modern replacement and it's supported since Windows Vista and OS X 10.4.0). That's not a problem though, MBR is still widely used and may have slightly better compatibility with hardware other than computers.

Initially only primary partitions existed and MBR has limited space reserved for storing their parameters, so you could only have 4 of them. This limitation exists to this day to preserve backwards compatibility. As the time passed it turned out that 4 partitions per disk are sometimes not enough. An *extended partition* was invented, which fits in a single partition slot of MBR partition table, replacing one primary partition. The extended partition can't store data, but it can store unlimited number of *logical disks*. Logical disks can be used exactly like primary partitions.

The whole partition table is read only once when the device is connected or when OS is told that the partition table might have changed (ie. almost never). Once it's loaded, OS already knows where partitions are located and doesn't care about their type anymore.

The only major drawback of extended partition is that it slightly limits repartitioning flexibility. Extended partition is usually the last one and sometimes users want to allocate more space to a logical disk inside of it. They shrink primary partitions at the beginning of hard disk and learn that they can't stretch their logical disk left because they would have to resize extended partition first. Repartitioning is not exactly a common thing, so I wouldn't consider it a major issue.

Comment: You are saying MBR support only 4 primary partitions so your are talking about in whole (for all drives in PC+external) or just 4 primary in single HDD?

Comment: But which is better in general - Primary or Logical?

Comment: Where is this MBR scheme stored? Is it different for different drives?

Comment: It's a data structure on a disk. It defines how that particular disk is partitioned. Primary partitions are limited to 4 (or 3 + extended partition), logical disks in an extended partition are not. I have yet to see a system that uses only an extended partition spanning a whole disk, there's probably a technical reason for that that I'm not aware of. Unless you're planning to repartition this disk you can leave it as is. It mostly doesn't matter.

Comment: So should I change my logical partition to primary type ? because the second primary partition(system image) will be hidden because I don't require it untill I find a solution for that ransomware.

Comment: In that case if you don't mind losing data on that logical partition, you could delete it and create a primary one. It will be easier to resize later.